# F# RSA decryption not working with separate public and private keys

Tags: .net-core, f#, rsa

I have the following code here:

```
let rsa = RSA.Create(2048)
let msg : byte[] = someBytes // 'someBytes' are just some bytes, not relevant for this example

let publicKey1 : byte[] = someBytes
let privateKey1 : byte[] = someBytes
let publicKey2 : byte[] = someBytes
let privateKey2 : byte[] = someBytes

rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(ReadOnlySpan<byte>(publicKey1), ref 2048)
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKey2), ref 2048)

let encryptedMsg = rsa.Encrypt(msg, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)

rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKey1), ref 2048)

let decryptedMsg = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedMsg , RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle key, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void* paddingInfo, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.Decrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at Program(Byte[] msg, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv) in ...
   at Program.main(String[] _arg1) in ...
```

When I remove the line `rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKey2), ref 2048)`, the code runs just fine.

My question is why is it that in the first case, the encryption depends somehow on the private key as well and when I decrypt, I get this error?

Comment: Instead of asking why doesn't it work I would ask why you are trying to use a single RSA instance to contain rsa keys from two different keypairs? Use a different RSA instance for each distinct use.

Comment: If anyone can explain this line from the [.Net RSA.ImportRSAPublicKey() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsapublickey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_ImportRSAPublicKey_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Int32__) I'd really appreciate it : "Imports the public key from a PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey structure after decryption, replacing the keys for this object." What possible relevance does the word "decryption" have to do with importing a public key?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Because I don't want to have the private key of the other RSA pair instance in the memory

Comment: I don't understand that, if you use any key at all then it has to be in memory.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I just want to encrypt with the public key only, if the public key is in memory, it doesn't matter, but if I have the private key as well, someone can get it and decrypt the message.